# Purpose/status of the attribute numpy.dtype.base

Tags: python, numpy

I have found an attribute called `base` on `numpy.dtype` objects. Doing some experiments:

```
numpy.dtype('i4').base
# dtype('int32')
numpy.dtype('6i4').base
# dtype('int32')
numpy.dtype('10f8').base
# dtype('float64')
numpy.dtype('3i4, 2f4')
# dtype([('f0', '<i4', (3,)), ('f1', '<f4', (2,))])
```

So it seems to contain the `dtype` of a single element for simple sub-array data types and itself for structured data types.

Unfortunately, this attribute does not seem to be documented anywhere. There *is* a [page in the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.base.html), but it’s empty and not linked anywhere. Curiously, it is also absent in the documentation for `numpy` version 1.15.0 specifically:

- [`/doc/numpy/…/numpy.dtype.base.html`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.base.html) (empty page)
- [`/doc/numpy-1.15.0/…/numpy.dtype.base.html`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.base.html) (error 404)
- [`/doc/numpy-1.15.1/…/numpy.dtype.base.html`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.base.html) (empty page)

Can I rely on the presence and behavior of this attribute in future versions of `numpy`?

Comment: It might be used in the construction of new compound dtypes, for example in the `recfunctions` module.

Comment: As for the doc pages, search github issues.

Comment: The `numpy.dtype` lists many attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now documented:

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.base.html#numpy.dtype.base

It is defined at https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/eeef9d4646103c3b1afd3085f1393f2b3f9575b2/numpy/core/src/multiarray/descriptor.c#L2255-L2300 and from git-blame was last touched ~13 years ago so it is probably safe to assume that `dtype.base` will exist and continue to exist.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether it's safe to rely on `base`, but it's probably a bad idea either way. People reading your code can't look up what `base` means in the docs, and anyway, there's a better option.

Instead of `base`, you can use [`subdtype`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.subdtype.html#numpy.dtype.subdtype), which *is* documented:

> Tuple `(item_dtype, shape)` if this [**dtype**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html#numpy.dtype) describes a
>   sub-array, and None otherwise.
>
> The *shape* is the fixed shape of the sub-array described by this data
>   type, and *item_dtype* the data type of the array.
>
> If a field whose dtype object has this attribute is retrieved, then
>   the extra dimensions implied by *shape* are tacked on to the end of
>   the retrieved array.

For a dtype that represents a subarray, `dtype.base` is equivalent to `dtype.subdtype[0]`. For a dtype that doesn't represent a subarray, `dtype.base is dtype` and `dtype.subdtype is None`. Here's a demo:

```
>>> subarray = numpy.dtype('5i4')
>>> not_subarray = numpy.dtype('i4')
>>> subarray.base
dtype('int32')
>>> subarray.subdtype
(dtype('int32'), (5,))
>>> not_subarray.base
dtype('int32')
>>> print(not_subarray.subdtype) # None doesn't get auto-printed
None
```

Incidentally, if you want to be sure about what `dtype.base` does, [here's the source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.15.2/numpy/core/src/multiarray/descriptor.c#L1925), which confirms what you guessed from your experiments:

```
static PyObject *
arraydescr_base_get(PyArray_Descr *self)
{
    if (!PyDataType_HASSUBARRAY(self)) {
        Py_INCREF(self);
        return (PyObject *)self;
    }
    Py_INCREF(self->subarray->base);
    return (PyObject *)(self->subarray->base);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used the `base` attribute, or seen it used.  But it does make sense that there should be a way of identifying such an object.  I can't find a use of it code such as in `np.lib.recfunctions`, but it may well be used in compiled code.

With a dtype like '10f8' there are various attritubes (some may be properties):

```
In [259]: dt = np.dtype('10f8')
In [260]: dt
Out[260]: dtype(('<f8', (10,)))
In [261]: dt.base
Out[261]: dtype('float64')
In [263]: dt.descr
Out[263]: [('', '|V80')]
In [264]: dt.itemsize
Out[264]: 80
In [265]: dt.shape
Out[265]: (10,)
```

Look what happens when we make an array with this dtype:

```
In [278]: x = np.ones((3,),'10f8')
In [279]: x
Out[279]: 
array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]])
In [280]: x.shape
Out[280]: (3, 10)
In [281]: x.dtype
Out[281]: dtype('float64')    # there's your base
```

**There's the answer - `dt.base` is the dtype that will be used in creating an array with the dtype.**  It's the dtype without the extra dimensional information.

That sort of dtype is rarely used by itself; more likely it is part of a compound dtype:

```
In [252]: dt=np.dtype('3i4, 2f4')
In [253]: dt
Out[253]: dtype([('f0', '<i4', (3,)), ('f1', '<f4', (2,))])
In [254]: dt.base
Out[254]: dtype([('f0', '<i4', (3,)), ('f1', '<f4', (2,))])
In [255]: dt[0]
Out[255]: dtype(('<i4', (3,)))
In [256]: dt[0].base
```

This `dt` could be embedded in another dtype:

```
In [272]: dt1 = np.dtype((dt, (3,)))
In [273]: dt1
Out[273]: dtype(([('f0', '<i4', (3,)), ('f1', '<f4', (2,))], (3,)))
In [274]: dt1.base
Out[274]: dtype([('f0', '<i4', (3,)), ('f1', '<f4', (2,))])
In [275]: arr = np.ones((3,), dt1)
In [276]: arr
Out[276]: 
array([[([1, 1, 1], [1., 1.]), ([1, 1, 1], [1., 1.]),
        ([1, 1, 1], [1., 1.])],
       [([1, 1, 1], [1., 1.]), ([1, 1, 1], [1., 1.]),
        ([1, 1, 1], [1., 1.])],
       [([1, 1, 1], [1., 1.]), ([1, 1, 1], [1., 1.]),
        ([1, 1, 1], [1., 1.])]],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4', (3,)), ('f1', '<f4', (2,))])
In [277]: arr.shape
Out[277]: (3, 3)
```

In the case of a structured array, the base of a field is the dtype that we get when viewing just that field.